# Select subset of delimited string field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table has a field with data formatted like this:

`Term 1~Term 2~Term 3~Term 4~Term 5~Term 6~`

All non-blank values contain 6 tilde-separated strings, which may be several words long.

I need to extract **the last 2 substrings from this field** as part of a query.
I'm not interested in splitting the data into multiple records, and I don't have permissions to create a stored procedure.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: I didn't create it, I just have to work with it. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DECLARE @Term VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @Term = 'abc~def~ghi~jkl~mno~pqr~'

```
SELECT RIGHT(@Term,  CHARINDEX('~',REVERSE(@Term),CHARINDEX('~',REVERSE(@Term),2)+1)-1)
```

That will give the last two terms with ~ intact.  Note you can wrap REPLACE() around that to put something other than the tilde in there.

Answer (score 0):

another way to do is this.. use string_split (in 2016) or an equivalent UDF that can be found elsewhere.. to split the string

```
    declare @term varchar(100) = 'abc~def~ghi~jkl~mno~pqr~'
; with mycte as (
select
 value as string_value
, row_number() over (order by (select  1000) )as row_num 
from string_split(@term,'~'))


select top 2 string_value 
 from mycte
 where string_value<>''

 order by row_num desc
```